# MySQL Query Not Working Properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Where is the mistake?

Thank you!

```
SELECT Table.id,
       Table.name,
   Table.kommentar,
   Table.pictureurl

   WHERE Table.news_id = 5, //without this line the query works!

   COUNT( Table1.comment_id ) AS numComments
   FROM DATABASE.news_comments          AS Table
   LEFT JOIN DATABASE.news_comments_comments AS Table1
   ON Table1.comment_id = Table.id

   GROUP BY Table.id
   ORDER BY Table.id DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHERE` clause should be after the `FROM` clause

```
SELECT `Table`.id,
       `Table`.name,
       `Table`.kommentar,
       `Table`.pictureurl,
       COUNT( Table1.comment_id ) AS numComments
FROM   DATABASE.news_comments          AS `Table`
          LEFT JOIN DATABASE.news_comments_comments AS Table1
             ON Table1.comment_id = `Table`.id
WHERE `Table`.news_id = 5    // <=== HERE
GROUP BY `Table`.id
ORDER BY `Table`.id DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

One more thing, your alias which is `Table` should be escape with backtick since it a **[Reserved Keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**

Comment: `table` needs to be escaped with backticks in `as table`

Comment: @Darwin: It is already fixed. The part `DATABASE.news_comments AS Table` needed backticks around `table` since `table` is a reserved word.

Comment: @Darwin Originally the `table` was not escaped. Thanks to juergen. :)

Comment: OK, so `TABLE` was just a placeholder for me. In my case it is something like user_blablabla, which mean that it does not need any back ticks, right? Thank you all!

Comment: Yes, backticks is used to escape reserved words. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table.id,
       Table.name,
   Table.kommentar,
   Table.pictureurl,   
   COUNT( Table1.comment_id ) AS numComments
   FROM DATABASE.news_comments  AS Table
   LEFT JOIN DATABASE.news_comments_comments AS Table1
   ON Table1.comment_id = Table.id

WHERE Table.news_id = 5   //===> where should be here

   GROUP BY Table.id
   ORDER BY Table.id DESC LIMIT 0,50
```